# Как изображение растянуть на весь footer?

Tags: html, вёрстка, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не получается растянуть изображение на ширину всего футера. Подскажите пожалуйста, как растянуть изображение на весь футер?

Comment: <footer class="footer-fixed-bottom">
    <img class="img footer-wraper img-responsive img-fluid" src="{% static 'gallery/image/BG/bg-footer.png' %}">
</footer> код футера

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, этот код в вопрос, и желательно `css` `footer-fixed-bottom`.

Comment: @Denis640Kb подождите пожалуйста

Comment: Предполагаю, что у Вас `footer` стоит ширина 100%. Если это так, то Вам необходимо обнулить отступы элементов `html` и `body`. Примерно так: `    html body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

В вопрос добавить данный код не могу, но могу сюда:

```
<footer class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
<img class="img footer-wraper img-responsive img-fluid" src="{% static 'gallery/image/BG/bg-footer.png' %}">
```

Comment: А зачем в вопрос добавлять данный код? Вы дали ответ или это уточнение вопроса?